# How can I convert an RGB color to a KML hexadecimal color string?

Tags: matlab, colors, kml, kmz

In MATLAB I have data defined by `x,y,z` coordinate values and color. Now I want to create a kmz file for Google Earth using the KLM Toolbox. In order to define a Color array I use the `'iconColor'` property for which the input *"Must be a valid hex color string input, in the style AABBGGRR"*.

What is a good way to transform my array of RGB colors to hex color strings? What if I want to use different colormaps (jet or winter)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [built-in colormaps](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) in MATLAB will give you matrices of RGB color triples that are scaled from 0 (lowest intensity) to 1 (highest intensity). To convert a single RGB triple to its [KML color style equivalent](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#colorstyle) (with the *AABBGGRR* format), the steps are:

- Scale it from 0 to 255.
- [Flip](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) the order to BGR.
- Add a transparency value to the beginning (0 for fully transparent, 255 for fully opaque).
- Convert to a [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) type to ensure you have integers in the range 0 to 255.
- Convert to hexdecimal strings using [`dec2hex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2hex.html).
- [Reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the result into a 1-by-8 array of characters.

And here is an example:

```
>> color = [1 1 0];  % The RGB triple for yellow
>> hexColor = reshape(dec2hex(uint8([255 255.*flip(color, 2)])).', 1, 8)

hexColor =

FF00FFFF
```

If you want to convert an entire colormap (i.e. an `N`-by-3 matrix, one RGB triple per row), you can modify the above code like so:

```
>> N = 10;        % Number of colors
>> map = jet(N);  % 10-by-3 jet colormap
>> hexMap = reshape(dec2hex(uint8([255.*ones(N, 1) 255.*flip(map, 2)]).').', 8, []).'

hexMap =

FFAA0000
FFFF0000
FFFF5500
FFFFAA00
FFFFFF00
FFAAFF55
FF55FFAA
FF00FFFF
FF00AAFF
FF0055FF
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful! 1 question - what is a good way to get RBG triples for my array of double values?

Comment: @NikkeyD: You would want to first create your colormap with `N` colors. Then scale your double values such that the minimum and maximum values are transformed to the range of 1 to `N`, then round them off to integer values to get row indices into your colormap for each double value.